# non-convex optimization with constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a special non-convex optimization problem:

$\min / \max \ f(x) + g(x) + h(x)$,

subject to $| g(x) - h(x)| < \varepsilon$,

where $f(x)$ is non-convex, but both $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are convex.

Is there any local implement algorithms to do that? I know maybe there is no global optima, so I just need the local optima.

If possible, can I have some pseudo code?

I try to use Lagrange multiplier,

$L(\lambda) = f(x) + g(x) + h(x) + \lambda(|g(x) - h(x)| - \varepsilon)$

or maybe for smooth case,

$L(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = f(x) + g(x) + h(x) + \lambda_1(g(x) - h(x) - \varepsilon) + \lambda_2(h(x) - g(x) - \varepsilon)$.

Then for some convex cases, we can find the analytical solution of $\lambda$ according to the gradients.

So how to obtain $\lambda$ and solve the problem numerically if there is no closed form solution.

In fact, here, $f$ is the sum of entropy and cross entropy of mixture Gaussian distribution. $g$ is one part of expected log likelihood (here likelihood is Gaussian or logistic) and $h$ is another part of expected log likelihood (here likelihood is Gaussian or logistic). $g + h$ is the whole expected log likelihood. Actually, it is constrained optimization for ELBO(Evidence lower bound) in variational inference.

Comment: perhaps it would be useful to give $f, g$ and $h$ concretely, there might be more structure to be exploited

Comment: I added the explanation of f,g,h. Actually, it is constrained optimization for ELBO(Evidence lower bound) in variational inference.